# Regular Expressions - Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am writing a test case script which installs Citrix Receiver, checks whether the store has been created and then uninstalls it.

The way I am uninstalling Receiver is by running this command:

```
Start-Process "C:\ProgramData\Citrix\Citrix Receiver 4.12\TrolleyExpress.exe" -argumentlist "/silent /uninstall /cleanup" -Wait -PassThru
```

The path to `TrolleyExpress.exe` and `/uninstall /cleanup` arguments are obtained from a registry key value. 
I have obtained the value contents and contained it into a variable:

```
$uninstallString = (Get-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\CitrixOnlinePluginPackWeb -name UninstallString).UninstallString
```

`$uninstallString` becomes `C:\ProgramData\Citrix\Citrix Receiver 4.12\TrolleyExpress.exe /uninstall /cleanup`

What I'm aiming for is to get the path to `TrolleyExpress.exe` from the regedit directly, since it is a test case which will run on multiple machines. In case the Receiver is installed on something different than `C:` or different path.

This is my first month into PowerShell Scripting and I'm quite new to Regular Expressions.

Any help\suggestion on how this could be solved is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the path in the registry follows the example you give (except possibly the drive letter), then one easy way to get just the path is:

```
$exePath = $uninstallString.Split('/')[0]
```

Comment: I suggest appending `.Trim()` to get rid of the trailing space.